# I can't seem to get strcmp working correctly

Tags: c

I'm trying something very simple; comparing a user inputted string to "hello" but strcmp does not want to work. I know I'm missing something obvious and I think it has to do with the way I declared my string. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char command[4555], compare[] = "hello";
    fgets (command, sizeof (command), stdin);
    printf ("%s\n%s\n", command, compare);
    if (strcmp (command, compare) == 0)
    {
        printf ("The strings are equal");
    } else {
        printf ("The strings are not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your printout prior to the test already tells you what the problem is. Why does it print out an empty line?

Comment: Should've done a bit more debugging. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` will leave the newline in the buffer and then null terminate while command will have no newline and just be null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

By using fgets you add a '\n' before the '\0' in your string.
By using :

```
if(command[strlen(command)-1]=='\n')
    command[strlen(command)-1]='\0';
```

You will delete it and effectively compare your strings

Comment: Even better would be to call `strlen(command)` once and use its result, stored in a variable, twice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to add something, Yes fgets appends a '\n' char to the input string.

So, its better to use strncmp function which is also in the same library.

strncmp (command, compare,strlen(command)-1) .

It works fine.