# strcmp() for lines within a file

Tags: c, string, fgets, strcmp, arrays

So I am trying to compare if a line in file is what I expect but even though when I print to console the first line of a file and what I expect and they look exactly the same THEY are not passing my strcmp test. This is how I test the first line of a file and what I expect:

```
char currentLine[MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH + 1]; // + 1 for terminating char
fgets(currentLine, MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH, inputFile);
assertCharArrayEquals(currentLine, "00000010000100011001000000100000\n");
```

My method assertCharArrayEquals looks like:

```
void assertCharArrayEquals(char *actualCharArray, char *expectedCharArray) {
    if (strcmp(actualCharArray, expectedCharArray) == 0) {
        printf("PASS: assertCharArrayEquals(%s, %s)\n", actualCharArray, expectedCharArray);
    } else {
        printf(">>>>>>>FAIL: assertCharArrayEquals(%s, %s)\n", actualCharArray, expectedCharArray);
    }
}
```

and my output to console looks like:

```
>>>>>>>FAIL: assertCharArrayEquals(00000010000100011001000000100000
, 00000010000100011001000000100000
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't seem to get strcmp working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166412/i-cant-seem-to-get-strcmp-working-correctly)

Comment: @Mat sorry I frogot to say even if i add \n to my test it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your output, `actualCharArray` ends with a newline character (`'\n'`), whereas `expectedCharArray` does not; therefore, they are not considered equal by `strcmp`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say that I tried adding the \n but it still didn't pass.

Comment: @Chingy: Well, `strcmp` is a very simple function to implement. You should have difficulty modifying `assertCharArrayEquals` to examine the characters using your own loop, so you can see exactly how it's going wrong. (After you've solved the problem, of course, you'll want to switch back to the `strcmp` version. But this approach is useful for debugging and understanding.)